# Prototype.js or other js function to decode html entities

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am looking for a prototype.js or other js function to decode html encoded entities.  I am using 1.6.1 of Prototype.js and unescapeHTML does not work on French encoded characters.  I believe from what I read, that is only works on a few select entities.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I would do something like this with javascript?  I would normally be able to use the .text() with jQuery, but right now the main library used is Prototype.

Thanks.

Comment: "French encoded characters" are HTML encoded French characters, I believe? It seems like this is a question about decoding arbitrary HTML-encoded strings.

Comment: Yeah, trying to get the right lingo here. Basically encoded HTML needs to be unencoded. The reason is the javascript outputs the html rather than the final output that a browser displays.

Comment: `unescapeHTML` and `escapeHTML` definitely only converts `<`, `>` and `&`. My question is how are you outputting with javascript that doesn't already decode?

Comment: A string is loaded into a js variable server side and the client side shows var somevar = "Mettre &agrave; jour" for example.  Then if you alert that or use that anywhere, it stays like that.  In the browser, the output ends up being &amp;agrave;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
function decode(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Doesn't return `&amp;` properly but works fine for french ones. Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/MRqnQ/3/

Comment: Yep, prototypes unescapeHTML doesn't work on those french html characters: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/MRqnQ/

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I can't change the output at this time as the strings are everywhere, I just can change the value of the string itself, so outputting the innerHTML isn't an option I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `decodeURI` function may be what you're looking for. It ignores "special" characters, but will turn an arbitrary URI-encoded string into what it represents.

Example:

```
encodeURI("Déjà vu") = "D%C3%A9j%C3%A0%20vu"

decodeURI("D%C3%A9j%C3%A0%20vu") = "Déjà vu"
```

---

An alternative may be to [use a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292320/use-javascript-regex-to-replace-numerical-html-entities-with-their-actual-charact).

Comment: Sorry the first option isn't what I am looking for, but the second looks like my only solution at this point.

Comment: Yes, the first option was just to show how the two functions go together. `decodeURI` is what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using that :

http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425