# How can I use regex to replace all $#8211; with &ndash; in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace all occurrences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064956/replace-all-occurrences-in-a-string)

I found this question/answer:

[Use JavaScript regex to replace numerical HTML entities with their actual characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292320/use-javascript-regex-to-replace-numerical-html-entities-with-their-actual-charac)

I just need to replace the one entity though. How can I match that specific pattern with a regex?

I don't know much about regex so I've done this:

```
.replace('&#8211;', '&ndash;')
```

But it obviously only replaces the first instance.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: What have you tried? (-1. Try something. Show what was tried and how it did/didn't work.) If you you need to replace one, no need for the `function` replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.replace(/&#8211;/g, '&ndash;')
```

the `g` flag means global so it replaces all instances.

Answer (score 4):

The `replace` method only replaces the first occurance when you are using a string. Use a regular expression, so that you can specify the global flag `g`:

```
.replace(/&#8211;/g, '&ndash;')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I accepted @Esailija answer as it was 1 min before yours.